# MySQL dump inside mysql console

Tags: mysql

Is there SQL command where you can do MySQL dump inside the MySQL console?

I tried mysqldump but it does not work...

I'm trying to output into SQL file.

Comment: Why you want this? Whats the problem with the output to sql file?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You cannot run mysqldump within a MySQL console since mysqldump is an external command like the mysql console.

Exit the console and use the mysqldump command as follows:

mysqldump -u username -p -h hostname (or ip address) databasename > sqlfilename

It will ask for password.

More details of mysqldump can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 18):

use `\!`:

```
\! mysqldump -u username -p database > database_dump.sql
```

[MySQL Documentation Reference (see System command)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html)

Comment: Note: This will only work when run in the MySQL Console directly and won't work via a SQL statement

Comment: [Note](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html): "The system command works only in Unix."

Comment: Also please note that this may not work in other MySQL command-line clients. For example, this won't work in mycli.

Answer (score 0):

use:

mysqldump -u username -p database

- database: name of database
- username: dbuser